# && Operator change the order of result

Tags: sql, postgresql

Why && operator of PostgreSQL 9.4 use for checking overlapping of two array, change the order of result?

I have a query

```
Select *  FROM "View_Student_Plan" WHERE  "ClassID" && ARRAY[53]:: bigint[]
```

My view is sorted in order of Admission date. 
It works fine, if I use

```
Select *  FROM "View_Student_Plan"
```

But when I attach remaining part with query it change the order of result.

I have used some other condition in where clause like `Student_Name like 'P%',` then it not affect order of result given by select statement. Then why don't for `"ClassID" && ARRAY[53]:: bigint[]`

Comment: If you need a certain order of your result, you should add a `ORDER BY` clause to your query. You shouldn't count on the order of queries or views which have no explicit order.

Comment: @macmoonshine But If I run query select * from "view..." then it works properly.

Comment: @Pooja-G it may, or tomorrow it may not. This false assumption is so strong sqlite even have a pragma to reverse select order just to make these bugs resurface. You cannot rely on something to be ordered if it is unordered by specification.

Comment: this has nothing to do with && and everything to do with VIEW.

Comment: SQL Server for example does not even allow `Order By` inside view (Except in conjunction with a `TOP` statement)

Comment: There is no such thing as "the order of the result" unless you have an `order by`

Comment: I have used some other condition in where clause like Student_Name like 'P%', then it not affect order of result given by select statement. Then why only "ClassID" && ARRAY[53]:: bigint[]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In any RDBMS the order of the output is not set by default, and can be sorted differently every time! It can be sorted by indexes, the optimizer, default set up and ETC..

The only way of forcing a specific order(E.G. by Admission date) , is by using the `ORDER BY` clause .

**EDIT:** Regarding to your comment, a `VIEW` can't contain an `ORDER BY` clause, it is not effective as this clause should be at the **end** of the query , otherwise , it can be ignored. 

E.G.

```
SELECT * FROM YourView
ORDER BY....--THIS WILL WORK
```

When it's inside the view its like:

```
SELECT * 
FROM (SELECT * FROM ....
      ORDER BY ..)
```

So the optimizer is free to ignore this.

Comment: I am using order by. "View_Student_Plan" is my view and query of this view contains order by clause.

Comment: @Pooja-G The `order by` needs to be at the very end of the query, otherwise it is ignored.

Comment: But If I run query select * from "view..." then it works properly.@Magnus

Comment: @Pooja-G I've added some explanation

Comment: Its working for me but still I am not getting proper explanation about why this happen.

Comment: @Pooja-G: The query optimiser uses a lot of different strategies to improve performance, but some of these (e.g. putting records in a temporary hash table) will completely change the ordering. The only way to guarantee the order is to put an `ORDER BY` in your final query. If you're curious to know what the optimiser is doing, run `EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM ...`.